# Cannot add new items into python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Hi I'm new to python. I am trying to add different key value pairs to a dictionary depending on different if statements like the following:

```
def getContent(file)
    for line in file:

        content = {}

        if line.startswith(titlestart):
            line = line.replace(titlestart, "")
            line = line.replace("]]></title>", "")
            content["title"] = line

        elif line.startswith(linkstart):
            line = line.replace(linkstart, "")
            line = line.replace("]]>", "")
            content["link"] = line

        elif line.startswith(pubstart):
            line = line.replace(pubstart, "")
            line = line.replace("</pubdate>", "")
            content["pubdate"] = line

    return content

print getContent(list)
```

However, this always returns the empty dictionary {}.

I thought it was variable scope issue at first but that doesn't seem to be it. I feel like this is a very simple question but I'm not sure what to google to find the answer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: wow that was such an amateur mistake. i figured it out literally 10 seconds after i posted this question. thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: Can you accept his answer as correct then by giving him the green tick?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You reinitialize `content` for every line, move the initialization outside of the loop:

```
def getContent(file)

    content = {}

    for line in file:
```

etc.